# Writing to a file in C

Tags: c, file, file-writing

Below i have a piece of code that i believe is very simple but for some reason will not work, as i get the error savedMap.c:20: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fPrintf’. The code is:

```
#include "Structures.h"
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void populateFile() {
    printf("The method is being called");
    FILE *f = fopen("tempMap.txt", "w");
    if(f == NULL) {
        printf("The tempMap file could not be found, please ensure the file is present.");
    }

    const char *text = mapFirstLine;
    fPrintf(f, "Some text", text);
}
```

Comment: `fPrintf` does not exist. `fprintf` does.

Comment: The warning: _implicit declaration of function ..._ should always be considered as an error_

Comment: If you got you problem solved, mark it as answered. [How to mark a answer as solution, and why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/285305)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace below the line instead of **fPrintf(f, "Some text", text);**

```
fprintf(f, "Some text", text);
```

Because **fPrintf ()** not predefined function in c.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `fPrinf()` function in `stdio.h`. You may want to use the standard library function `fprintf()` instead, like this:

```
fprintf(f, "Some text", text);
```

The reason why an "implicit decalration" warning is emitted is that the return value of an undeclared function is `int` by default in C.